# Should login_url for permission_required check the permission?

Tags: django

Simple question..?  The `permission_required` decorator (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator) allows you to specify a `login_url` parameter. Should the view that handles this url check the permission (in addition to logging the user in)? ..or will the `permission_required` decorator handle it?

I can't find anything in the docs, and while I can see that `permission_required` checks the permission before trying to log the user in, it doesn't look like it checks the permission after `login_url` has logged the user in (but I must admit I get lost in `user_passes_test`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need not check for the permissions. That is what the decorator does. If there is no permission, then the request is redirected to the login url. So, the user has to again reach the url, which means the decorator again checks for the permissions. So, if you use the decorator, you need not check inside the view again.

Comment: Ah, of course. I didn't catch that the `permission_required` decorator is called twice (`permission_required(view) -> login -> permission_required(view) -> view`).

Comment: @thebjorn Exactly. If you see, the url changes when there is no permission for the user. This means that the request is redirected